# How do I open and read from a file in x86_64 GAS Assembly in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, 64-bit, gnu, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to replicate a lower-to-upper string program, which will open a file, run the code, and print it on screen. but i want to try and open a test file first - without the hassle of trying to read what the user typed.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, %rax's value is 3 after the first system call, which I understand is an error.

```
    .data

filename:
    .asciz "test.txt"

inputInFile:
    .string ""

.text
.global _start

_start:

#TO-DO: ASK FOR FILENAME

#open file syscall
mov $2,%rax
mov $filename,%rdi
mov $0,%rsi
mov $0666,%rdx
syscall


#TO-DO: ERROR FOR FILE NOT FOUND


.Loop:
#reading from file syscall, into buffer
mov $0, %rax
mov $0, %rdi
mov $inputInFile, %rsi
mov $500,%rdx
syscall
#input is in rax

#in case of end of file,  close file
cmp $0,%rax
je .exit

#append input into buffer
mov %rax,%rdx
mov $1,%rax
mov $1,%rdi
mov $inputInFile,%rsi
syscall

jmp .Loop

#close file syscall
mov $3,%rax
mov $1,%rdi
syscall


.exit:
#close file
mov $3,%rax
mov $1,%rdi
syscall

#quit
mov $60,%rax
mov $0,%rdi
syscall
```

Comment: No, `3` is not an error, it's the descriptor for the file you just opened. Errors are negative. Since you normally have `0`, `1` and `2` already used for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, opening a file will usually give you `3`. You will have to pass this to the `read` though, where you are passing `0` and to the `write`/`close` where you pass `1` for whatever reason. Comment your code better. See also man pages for [open](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open), [read](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read), [write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) and [close](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

Comment: Use `strace ./a.out` to see the system calls your process makes.

Comment: [How to append to a file using x86-64 Linux system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48541868) is related, using NASM syntax but still showing what numbers need to go in which registers.