# How to append to a file using x86-64 Linux system calls?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

I'm creating a file and then opening it using system calls.

Creating:

```
mov rax, 85
mov rdi, path
mov rsi, 400
syscall
```

Opening:

```
mov rax, 2
mov rdi, path
mov rsi, 2 ; I found somewhere that I should use 400 to append
syscall
mov r8, rax ; save the file handle
```

Writing:

```
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, r8
mov rsi, output
mov rdx, length
syscall
```

After I complete these steps I close the file naturally, however I am unable to append to it and each time I perform these actions it just rewrites the content of the file, but for example I calculated the first n prime numbers and stored them away in some chunk of memory and now I'd like to write those n prime numbers down in the file, but I'm not able to do so without appending more lines.

Also is there a way to not specify the length of the string for `write` in `rdx`, but instead have the string be terminated by a `/0`?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions in one post.  Please limit each post to a single question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`O_APPEND` by itself would imply `O_RDONLY` (because it's `0`), not `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`.  Opening read-only for append isn't usually useful.  As in C, you need to OR together multiple flags to get a file descriptor you can use to write at the end of the file, even if its length is changed by something other than than your writes.

---

For appending to a file use the `O_APPEND = 0x400` flag as `int flags` parameter in `rsi`. So you were close: it's a value of hexadecimal 400 and not decimal 400 as you attempted.

Here is a list of the raw `int flags` values in hexadecimal:

```
O_ACCMODE                        = 0x3
O_APPEND                         = 0x400
O_ASYNC                          = 0x2000
O_CLOEXEC                        = 0x80000
O_CREAT                          = 0x40
O_DIRECT                         = 0x4000
O_DIRECTORY                      = 0x10000
O_DSYNC                          = 0x1000
O_EXCL                           = 0x80
O_FSYNC                          = 0x101000
O_LARGEFILE                      = 0x0
O_NDELAY                         = 0x800
O_NOATIME                        = 0x40000
O_NOCTTY                         = 0x100
O_NOFOLLOW                       = 0x20000
O_NONBLOCK                       = 0x800
O_RDONLY                         = 0x0
O_RDWR                           = 0x2
O_RSYNC                          = 0x101000
O_SYNC                           = 0x101000
O_TRUNC                          = 0x200
O_WRONLY                         = 0x1
```

So this should work:

```
mov   rax, 2
lea   rdi, [rel path]
mov   rsi, 0x441        ; O_CREAT| O_WRONLY | O_APPEND
mov   edx, 0q666        ; octal permissions in case O_CREAT has to create it
syscall
mov   r8, rax      ; save the file descriptor
```

I added the three values to create the file if it doesn't exist or open it in write_only mode if it does exist.  You could define them as assemble-time `equ` constants so you could actually write `mov esi, O_CREAT| O_WRONLY | O_APPEND` in your source.

Also, make sure to supply a value for the 3rd arg (permissions) any time you include O_CREAT.  Otherwise the file could get created with random garbage for its permissions, including possibly setuid + exec.  Normally you pass octal `666` (NASM `0q666`) and let the user's umask knock off write permission for other and optionally group.

If you don't actually want open to create it if it doesn't already exist, omit O_CREAT.  Then it will return `-ENOENT`.

---

> Also is there a way to not specify the length of the string in rdx, but instead have the string be terminated by a /0?

In short: No.
Create a `strlen` function and pass the result in `rdx`.  Kernel system calls take data to be read/written on file descriptors as buffer + length, only pathnames as C implicit-length strings.

Comment: According to [Linux sys\_open in 64-bit NASM returns negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59202746), these constants are defined in `/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h`.  (With the call number for `open` coming from `asm/unistd_64.h`)

Comment: For the record: `mov rdi, path` is a crappy way to put a label address in a register. 
 Use `lea rdi, [rel path]` for the standard position-independent way, or `mov edi, path` for the optimized Linux non-PIE executable way.  You basically never want to use a 64-bit absolute address; it's inefficient.  [How to load address of function or label into register in GNU Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)