# Linux sys_open in 64-bit NASM returns negative value

Tags: linux, x86-64, nasm

I am opening an existing file to write into it, using sys_open and sys_write.  The sys_write works correctly when I create a new file as shown below.  But if I use sys_open, the return value is negative (-13, which is "Permission denied") and the write doesn't work (of course).

This works:

```
section .data
File_Name: db '/opt/Test_Output_Files/Linux_File_Test',0
File_Mode: dq 754q
Write_Buffer: db 'This is what I want to write',0

section .text

; Create file
mov rax,85 ; sys_creat
mov rdi,File_Name
mov rsi,File_Mode  ; mode (permissions)
syscall

mov rdi,rax ; return code from sys_creat
mov rax,1 ; sys_write
mov rsi,Write_Buffer
mov rdx,29
syscall
```

But when I open the existing file, the sys_open command fails:

```
mov rax,2 ; sys_open
mov rdi,File_Name
mov rsi,2 ;read-write
mov rdx,[File_Mode]
syscall
```

Because this is a permissions error, the issue is most likely the flags value in rsi because the mode value in rdx is the same as I use with sys_creat (754).  According to the Linux man pages at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html and  https://linux.die.net/man/3/open, there are three required options:

```
O_RDONLY - Open for reading only. 
O_WRONLY - Open for writing only. 
O_RDWR - Open for reading and writing. The result is undefined if this flag is applied to a FIFO.
```

I know that read-only is zero, so I assumed write only and read-write are 1 and 2, but I haven't found any listing of the numeric values that we would use in assembly language, unlike the mode which is based on chmod -- and it's the same mode value I used for create, which works.

I've researched this extensively, but there is sparse information on 64-bit syscalls -- most of it is 32-bit.  For NASM I need to use a numeric value for the flags in rsi.  The man pages say "In addition, zero or more file creation flags and file status flags can be bitwise-or'd in flags.  The file creation flags are O_CLOEXEC, O_CREAT, O_DIRECTORY, O_EXCL, O_NOCTTY, O_NOFOLLOW, O_TMPFILE, and O_TRUNC."  I could bitwise OR them if I knew what their values are.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Try to encode your mode directly with mov rsi, 0754o.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Comment: _"the return value is negative"_ What, exactly, is it though? I.e. which specific error are you getting?

Comment: @RTC222 whats the value in rax register after executing the syscall instruction? You said negative but what is the actual number?

Comment: I updated the question above - the return value is -13, Permission denied.  That suggests that the issue is, as I said above, the flags value in rsi.  I haven't found any source of the numeric values for the flags so I can xor them to create the correct value.  The values in the Linux man pages are fine for C programs, but not for assembly.

Comment: what do you get for ls -l /opt/Test_Output_Files/Linux_File_Test?

Comment: -r--r-xr-t 1 username username 29 Dec  6 18:28 /opt/Test_Output_Files/Linux_File_Test

Comment: So, you don't have rw permission. that explains the -13 error. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, you do not have O_RDWR permission for the file that you are trying to open.

You should try O_RDONLY.

Anyway, to answer your question.
As far as flag values are concerned, those will be:

```
O_CREAT(0x40)
O_TRUNC(0x200)
O_APPEND(0x400)
```

You can find the entire list in:

```
/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h
```

Note: if O_CREAT is not set then 'mode' (the value that you set in rdx) will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll work with this and post back later.  Why O_RDONLY?   I need to write to this file.  It was created with write permission.  The include file you referenced will likely lead to the right combination.

Comment: Just to test if O_RDONLY works or not. Once that is confirmed, you will have to figure out why sys_create isn't setting the correct permission to your file. i.e. you want rw

Comment: According to fcntl.h, that's zero.  I'll try that now.

Comment: Read-only (0) works.  Write only (1) and read-write (2) both fail with -13 Permission denied.

Comment: What puzzles me most is that the permissions mask returned by ls -l doesn't show write permission, but the file is created with write permission and if I follow the call to create with a call to sys_write, the write succeeds.  I'm still working on this.

Comment: In your sys_creat call, you have mov rsi,File_Mode Shouldn't that be mov rsi,[File_Mode]

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  That works (with a return code of 0 for the create).  Now I will try to open the same file.  Maybe that was its problem.

Comment: Yes, you hit the nail on the head.  The problem with sys_write was that sys_create must be created with the mode passed as a value, not as a pointer.  I wonder why sys_create worked with a pointer instead of a value.

Comment: It simply took the address value (pointer) and interpreted as permission.

Comment: By coincidence, I imagine.  Thanks very much for your help.