# writing to file using syscalls in x86_64 assembly (not NASM)

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, att

*Before I start writing this question, just in case it gets flagged for duplicates: this is NOT using NASM syntax. All the other questions use NASM, which I don't know. Anyways:*

I'm trying to simply write to a txt file using x86_64 assembly (GNU), and I can't seem to get the desired write outcome. I'm using the open, write, and close syscall codes to achieve my goal, but apparently to no avail. I am compiling using the following commands:

```
sudo as -o db.o db.S
sudo ld -s -o db db.o
./db
```

Here is my assembly code. You can pretty much ignore all print and println functions, the main one I'm concerned about is `write_to_txt_file`:

**EDIT: I just learned how to run this through gdb and %rax (the return register) after the first syscall in the write function was -22. I have no idea what this means but I'm doing research. For your reference, this is in Linux**

**EDIT 2: someone mentioned using strace. When I do, this is the output. I have never used strace before, so I have no clue what to do with this info, but I'm going to do some research while waiting for other responses**

[image]

**EDIT 3: I have made changes according to the suggestions in the comments, and now have error code -2 instead of -22. It seems like the program is struggling to find my text file, despite the .S file being in the same directory as my txt file**

**EDIT 4: Using `strace cat database.txt` and `strace tee database.txt`, I get the following outputs near the end:**

cat:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "database.txt", O_RDONLY) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
mmap(NULL, 139264, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6126f1d000
read(3, "", 131072)                     = 0
munmap(0x7f6126f1d000, 139264)          = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

tee:
*doesn't finish running. I have to use ctrl-c to exit it. I then get this:*

```
strace: Process 19309 detached
 <detached ...>
```

**EDIT 5: moved filename to the top of my data declarations. Now when I run strace, I get this:**
[image]

**EDIT 6: this issue is now solved. I have put the working function below if anyone else is going through similar confusions**

***ACTUAL CODE***

```
write_to_txt_file:
#%rdi must hold an address to a character array, like mov $buf, %rdi
#%rsi must hold %rdi's length, like mov $tlen, %rsi

    push %rdi
    push %rsi

    #open file:
    mov $0x2, %rax
    mov $filename, %rdi
    mov $0x61, %rdx
    mov $0x441, %rsi
    syscall

    mov %rax, %r8

    #write to file:
    mov $0x1, %rax
    mov %r8, %rdi
    pop %r13    #contents of %rdi which were pushed onto the stack get popped into %r12
    pop %r12    #^^same but with length
    mov %r12, %rsi
    mov %r13, %rdx
    syscall

    ret
```

Comment: Assuming this is Linux, a return code of -22 is EINVAL  -- Invalid Argument

Comment: @ChrisDodd so would this mean that something like my filename is wrong? Also, yes, I edited the question to specify that this is Linux.

Should I include a path instead of just a file name?

Comment: or the flags to `open` are incorrect -- those are in `%esi` which you don't set.

Comment: @ChrisDodd thanks again! I tried putting 0x400 into %rsi, which according to another stack overflow post, should be the append flag, but I'm still having no luck. Still getting -22 in %rax

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Running the program under `strace ./db` will decode the args.  (And the return value as EINVAL)

Comment: Learning enough NASM to be able to *read* it is much easier than being able to write it.  Since you already know the basics of one x86-64 assembly language, you know what's possible in a single instruction.  The only thing you need to know is that the destination's on the left in NASM like in Intel's manuals, and memory operands always have square brackets, register or immediate never do.  So `mov esi, message` is NASM for putting a symbol address into a register, like you'd do in GAS with `mov $message, %esi` or `lea message(%rip), %rsi`.

Comment: `strace` shows you C source that would make the system call your code made.  Check it against the man page (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).  In this case, it reveals at least 2 problems: filename is an empty string (perhaps because you didn't zero-terminate it with `.asciz`?) and what Chris pointed out, that you don't set the second arg, `int flags` in ESI, so there's some garbage.  And the create mode is a surprising `0141` (octal).

Comment: [How to append to a file using x86-64 Linux system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48541868) shows the relevant NASM instructions to make the open system call you want.  The instructions are just putting constants (or an address) into registers, so it's straightforward to see which register gets which constant even if you're don't know NASM syntax.  (`0q666` is NASM for octal, in GAS you just use `0666`).  I agree it's not an exact duplicate, unlike your other recent question about returning from start where the text of the duplicate explaining the concept in English was the answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you!! I'll make those string fixed immediately and get back to you. In the meantime, I've been searching the internet and can't find articles/posts that agree on what to put in %rsi if you're trying to append. Also, is the 0141 code you gave me in hex?

Comment: `0141` C and GNU-assembler syntax for octal, like I said.  `0141` is the `0x61` you put into EDX, the third arg.  `strace` is decoding it in octal because it's the mode in case the file gets created, and modes aka permissions have 3-bit groups for read/write/exec for owner/group/other, in that order.  Maybe you meant to put that value into ESI, as the `flags` arg?  As shown in the NASM answer I linked, the value you want is `0x441`, `O_CREAT| O_WRONLY | O_APPEND`.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, this helped a lot. I'm getting a slightly different strace output right now, which seems to indicate that the file was not found. This kind of goes back to one of my original questions: should I give the program a file name or a full path? Keep in mind they're in the same directory currently

Comment: Look at the `flags` you passed (as decoded by `strace`): they don't include `O_CREAT` so it won't create the file, it has to already exist for the call to succeed.  And if it did, you'd get a read-only file descriptor.  Also, if `strace`'s interpretation of the path matches the kernel's it's still trying to open the empty string, which isn't a valid filename, but that should return -EINVAL rather than -ENOENT.  The path can be a relative path.  If `echo >> foo.txt` works, `./db` will work if it uses `foo.txt` as the path.  Try `strace tee foo.txt` and `strace cat foo.txt` to see what they do.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to (and shouldn't) use `sudo` to assemble this.  Having the program owned by root is not helpful, and it's a bad habit to run stuff (like the assembler + linker) as root when you don't need.

Comment: @PeterCordes the file already exists, and I don't want to keep re-creating it every time the code runs because I want to append to it. This project is supposed to be a really really really simple CRUD database. 

Also, echo >> database.txt works, but strace cat and strace tee both give REALLY long outputs that have -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument) somewhere in the first 2 lines.

Comment: You didn't use `O_TRUNC` so it won't be truncated / replaced if it exists; `O_CREAT` only applies if it doesn't exist; if it does it just opens it.  I assumed it didn't because you got `-ENOENT`, but perhaps that's just bad error reporting by the kernel for the empty string as a path.  Yeah, I tried a C program on my system (Linux kernel 6.5) that does `int fd = open("", 0x441, 0666);` (which is `open("", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666)` and I also get an `ENOENT` return, not the `EINVAL` the man page says we should in that case.

Comment: BTW, if you aren't familiar with POSIX / Linux system calls, you can play around with them in C or some other language you do know which has wrappers for them.  Learning how to use them is a totally separate problem from learning assembly, which adds the additional challenge of finding actual numeric values for constants like `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR` (which is the other key thing you're missing).

Comment: Re: `strace` on `tee` or `cat`: yes, dynamically linked executables make a lot of system calls during startup (some of which return errors, like `arch_prctl` and `access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)` on my system).  They only get to the interesting part very near the end.  That's what you should be looking for, an `open("database.txt", ...` (or actually `openat(AT_FDCWD, "database.txt", ...)` on modern Linux), and a `read` or `write` using that fd.  You can also filter which system calls, like file-related ones (incl. open) plus read and write with `strace -e file,read,write cat database.txt`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I edited the question with the results from the strace tee and cat runs (titled edit 4)

Comment: The current code in your question doesn't match your strace. (I commented out the `callq println` and the `...` lines.  Perhaps they overwrite your filename in `.data`?  Put string constants in `.rodata` and/or debug your code or simplify your [mcve]).  It makes four system calls: `open("database.txt", O_RDONLY|O_APPEND) = 3` which successfully opens an existing file, but for reading only.

Comment: Then, ignoring the `fd` from open, it writes to stdout with `write(1, "txt\n", 4)  = 4`, then closes stdout with `close(1)  = 0` and exits with `exit(0)`.  If it tried to `write(fd, msg, 4)`, it would get `-EBADF` because you still haven't used `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`, like shown in [How to append to a file using x86-64 Linux system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48541868)   (`O_RDONLY` is `0`, so you get that if you omit all three flags.  Other open flags are single set bits at other positions, outside the low 2 bits.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you were right about my filename getting rewritten by the other data. I moved it to the top of the data declarations, and I edited the question accordingly. I still don't get the desired writing output, but now I think the issue is something else. I've linked the new strace. Also, in that new strace, it seems like I am using wronly

Comment: Yes, your `flags` are finally correct and `open` succeeds.  But you don't use the FD from RAX in your `write` system call, you're still writing to stdout (fd=1).  (Your create mode in EDX is wrong, though; you don't want to create it with 141 permission (exec-only for owner, read for group, exec-only for other).  Use `0666`, or don't use `O_CREAT` and don't set EDX at all if you want it to fail when the file doesn't exist.)

Comment: @PeterCordes everything works now. Thank you SO SO SO much for all your help, as well as your consistent, timely, and useful responses

Comment: Glad I could help.  You should post your working version as an *answer* to your question, not as an edit.  Click the "answer my own question" button.  (It's better if you write some text explaining what you changed *and why*, or at least comment the asm with things like `mov $0666, %edx   # mode (permissions) if file does get created` instead of the non-useful `mov $0141, %edx` which you wrote as `mov $0x61, %rdx`)

Comment: R12 and R13 are call-preserved regs so this function isn't safe to call from C.  Use R9 and R10, or pop directly into RSI and RDX.  (RCX and R11 are clobbered by `syscall`).